# Using pipes-csv to parse Latin-1 encoded content?

Tags: csv, haskell, haskell-pipes

I'd like to use `pipes-csv` to parse some large CSV files, but it turns out these CSV files are Latin-1 encoded and it also turns out that `pipes-csv`, and the `cassava` library it depends on, assume UTF-8. This ends up producing parsing errors that I need to handle.

The way I've approached it is to duplicate the records that will hold CSV data so that all the `Text` fields are `ByteString` fields in the dup. I decode into the dup, then manually translate the Latin-1 strings into UTF-8 and create the final record. Inelegant to say the least.

Is there a better way?

---

Per Daniel's suggestion, here is what I have so far:

```
import qualified Pipes.Text.Encoding as PTE
import qualified Pipes.ByteString as PB

withFile "file.csv" ReadMode $ \h -> do
  let transcode = PTE.decodeIso8859_1 . PB.fromHandle ~> PTE.encodeUtf8
  runEffect $ decodeByName (void . transcode $ h) >-> process
```

It trades off unnecessary records for unnecessary re-encoding of the text, but it's an improvement. I don't suppose there is a way to do this without doing either of these unnecessary things?

Comment: You could consider throwing a pipe on the front that converts Latin-1 encoded `ByteString`s into UTF-8 encoded `ByteString`s.

Comment: @DanielWagner So you mean decode to Text, re-encode to ByteString, and then let pipes-csv decode again into Text?

Comment: @frivat this seems exactly right. `delatin p = void $ for (Text.decodeIso8859_1 p) Text.encodeUtf8`, or as you write it. The problem is with `cassava`, not `pipes-csv`, which works with bytestring, but assumes they are utf8 encoded. This is an optimization which turns out not to be ideal in this case (I think that's the whole story). The encoding and decoding functions from `streaming-commons` are pretty efficient so hopefully the unpleasant detour won't be too costly.

Comment: @frivat Right. Unless you want to hack on cassava/pipes-csv directly...

Comment: This seems to be a very typical problem. ByteString is not intended for representing text formats, so working with any concept of "encoding" beyond "raw bits/bytes" with a ByteString is usually a headache. You can do it if you want, but of course, you can also hammer a nail with a screwdriver. If you are working with UTF8 encoded strings, you should consider converting them to `Text` immediately and writing all of your functions to work with `Text`. If one of your dependencies only works with ByteString.. you may be SOL, i.e. stuck with the ugly solution you have now.

Comment: @user2407038 Yes, in the ideal world, everything is uniform.